# Does the arc indicate the exact percentage of the max CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

For example, let's say a Pokémon I have is 100 CP and the arc is about halfway does that mean that I can expect it to be 200 CP when maxed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the arc does indicate the percentage of the way through the "CP Progression" a Pokemon is. However, as your trainer level increases, so does the maximum CP of your Pokemon (up to a built-in limit for each Pokemon). Because of this, when your trainer  level increases, if you had a filled CP arc before, there will be a little bit more room in it upon leveling up.
See: [List of Pokemon sorted by maximum CP values](http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-list).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. 50% is easy to identify but with the rest, guessing is more than enough to know what max CP is expected. Rememeber that leveling up your trainer, makes the max CP increase so if you have now 100 CP and represents 50% , when you level up you will have 100 CP and it could represent for example 45%